# Linux, Python open terminal run global python command

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

Not sure if this is possible. I have a set of python scripts and have modified the linux PATH in ~/.bashrc so that whenever I open a terminal, the python scripts are available to run as a command.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/pythonlib/
```

my_command.py resides in the above path.

I can run my_command.py (args) from anywhere in terminal and it will run the python scripts.

I'd like to control this functionality from a different python script as this will be the quickest solution to automating my processing routines. So I need it to open a terminal and run my_command.py (args) from within the python script I'm working on.

I have tried subprocess:

```
import subprocess
test = subprocess.Popen(["my_command.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = test.communicate()[0]
```

While my_command.py is typically available in any terminal I launch, here I have no access to it, returns file not found.

I can start a new terminal using os then type in my_command.py, and it works

```
os.system("x-terminal-emulator -e /bin/bash")
```

So, is there a way to get the second method to accept a script you want to run from python with args?

Ubuntu 16

Thanks :)

Comment: The executable is called `my_command.py`, not `my_command`.  What is `$my_command`?  Is there a shell variable called `my_command` which you expect python to know about?

Comment: From terminal, I just have to type "my_command" not with the .py. Adding the .py in subprocess makes no difference. my_command is just a python file my_command.py.

Comment: `my_command`, `my_command.py`, and `$my_command` are three different things, or do you have a symbolic link?  This is not  Windows, it does not add the extension automagically, or are you using an alias in the shell?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. $ was just indicating the terminal window. I didn't write "my-command" anywhere? When you register the PATH of the python project, you can reference the file my_command.py as just my_command from a terminal window.

Comment: Aliasing in shell.

Comment: Sorry,, I'll simplify the question to just the my_command.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Popen does not load the system PATH for the session you create in a python script. You have to modify the PATH in the session to include the directory to your project like so:

```
someterminalcommand = "my_command.py (args)"

my_env = os.environ.copy()
my_env["PATH"] = "/home/usr/mypythonlib/:" + my_env["PATH"]

combine = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(someterminalcommand), env=my_env)

combine.wait()
```

This allows me to run my "my_command.py" file from a different python session just like I had a terminal window open.

Comment: Uh, this is the exact answer to the question I posted. Why would someone down-vote it?

Comment: I wouldn't know. I don't event know why my answer got downvoted, although I'm pretty confident it's showcasing a good use of `gnome-terminal` with Python - I'm using it pretty often. Anyway, I upvoted your answer, since it's quite good :)

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Gnome, the `gnome-terminal` command is rather useful in this situation.

As an example of very basic usage, the following code will spawn a terminal, and run a Python REPL in it:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "-e", "python"])
```

Now, if you want to run a specific script, you will need to concatenate its path with `python`, for the last element of that list it the line that will be executed in the new terminal.
For instance:

```
subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "-e", "python my_script.py"])
```

If your script is executable, you can omit `python`:

```
subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "-e", "my_script.py"])
```

If you want to pass parameters to your script, simply add them to the `python` command:

```
subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "-e", "python my_script.py var1 var2"])
```

Note that if you want to run your script with a particular version of Python, you should specify it, by explicitly calling "python2" or "python3".

---

A small example:

```
# my_script.py
import sys
print(sys.argv)
input()

# main.py
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "-e", "python3 my_script.py hello world"])
```

Running `python3 main.py` will spawn a new terminal, with `['my_script.py', 'hello', 'world']` printed, and waited for an input.