# Write a python script that enters commands on an ubuntu terminal?

Tags: python, ubuntu, spyder, gnome-terminal, os.system

I am using spyder on ubuntu 16.04.  I want to write a script that will execute several commands in the same linux terminal.

First I want to open a terminal, then ssh into another computer, then enter my password, then continuing entering commands.

I have tried `os.system(command)` but this does not open a new terminal for me nor run the command I want.

`os.system("gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"ssh blah blah blah; exec bash\"'")`
 works but I am stuck when trying to enter my password.

How can I enter commands with a Python script in this context?

Comment: Try to make the SSH connection using the paramiko library - but as currently stated your question is likely to be closed as too broad.

Comment: Possibly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python

Comment: You might find useful the answer I gave [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48372732/7051394)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to automatically connect & login to an ssh server with a password, you can use `sshpass` to enter the password, but it'd be better to use an SSH key. Github has a good tutorial on how to generate a key [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/).

If you're looking to execute commands after SSHing into your server, you can do so with: `os.system("ssh user@host 'command1 && command2'")`

Answer (score 0):

For executing commands on a terminal you can use python's subprocess module. There's already a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17742789/running-multiple-bash-commands-with-subprocess) on how to execute multiple commands using a single terminal with subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module along with the [`gnome-terminal`](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-gnome-terminal/) command if you're using Gnome.

The idea is to spawn a GUI terminal, and to execute a script into it through the `-e` option.
Here is a very simple example, on how to execute a shell script in a new terminal.

*`myscript.sh`*

```
#!/bin/bash

pwd
ls
cat
```

*`spawn_and_run.py`*

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["gnome-terminal", "-e", "myscript.sh"])
```

Running `python spawn_and_run.py` will spawn a new terminal, print the working directory (`pwd`), print the content of that directory (`ls`), and then echo the input from `stdin` (`cat` without arguments).

Comment: @Robot12341 Glad it helped! Don't hesitate to give a +1, to accept an answer, or simply to provide feedback, we're all learning here :)